# How to get coordinates by click on map and send coordinate to MySQL?

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinates, mysql

I'm building my own web map.

Now I want to get the coordinates by click on the map and send the coordinates to MySQL.

I tried OpenLayers to get the coordinates from Openstreetmap,but I didn't know how to send it to my MySQL.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Register click event ( See https://codezone4.wordpress.com/2013/04/06/getting-the-coordinates-of-a-click-in-openlayers-map/ for example).
Then send the grabbed coordinates with an Ajax request to a php file ( http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392036/send-data-to-mysql-with-ajax-jquery-php )

Comment: PHP? D: Or Python, Java, C#, Nodejs and about 27 others, though it is true, PHP is often paired with MySQL.

Comment: whats wrong with PHP in your opinion?

Comment: Nothing at all. Just making the point that there are other options for inserting coordinates into MySQL than PHP.

Comment: it would be unlikely to avoid web layer (i.e. some webapp in programming lanuages like php or java) for inserting the data to the db. unlikely it is possible to inset it directly to the db

Comment: a node-js example http://dclure.org/logs/populating-mysql-tables-with-node-js/